# Must a locally compact group be Hausdorff in order to possess a Haar measure?

Tags: haar-measure, topological-groups

Does the existence of (left) Haar measure on a locally compact topological group require that the group be Hausdorff?

Comment: No, you can do the usual construction on the Kolmogorov quotient (which is locally compact Hausdorff) and pull the measure back on the original group.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not sure about "pull the measure back". Generally one can push measures forward though. 

Comment: The group on 2 elements with the indiscrete topology is locally compact, I think it has a Haar measure for any definition I can think of. Anyway, the question is unclear since "Haar measure" should be defined in a way that the question makes sense.

Comment: @ToddTrimble since Borel subsets of a topological group are invariant by the closure of $\{1\}$, the definition of "pull the measure back" is clear. In general, if $f:X\to Y$ is a map and you have a $\sigma$-algebra and measure on $Y$, the pull-back of the $\sigma$-algebra is the set of $f^{-1}(B)$, $B$ in the $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$, and the measure is clearly defined. This construction is quite trivial and uninteresting but precisely is fine for this question.

Comment: @YCor: You say that *"the measure is clearly defined"*. Could you please make this part explicit for the slower ones of us ("lourds d'esprit")? I believe that the pullback measure should be $(f^* \mu) (B) = \mu (f (B))$, and it is not clear why $f(B)$ should be Borel when $B$ is Borel, and why this should give a measure. Or am I misunderstanding what "pullback measure" is supposed to mean here?

Comment: @AlexM. because I only define the pull-back measure on the pulled-back $\sigma$-algebra, i.e., on the sets of the form $f^{-1}(C)$ with $C$ measurable in $Y$.

Comment: @YCor: Can you show that $f^{-1} (C)$ is, in general, not equal to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$? As an example, I was thinking about Abelian varieties with the Zariski topology, but I do not really know much about this, and I do not know any other interesting example of non-Hausdorff topology.

Comment: @AlexM. $f^{-1}(C)$ belongs to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, this makes no sense. Maybe you mean $\{f^{-1}(C)\}$ when $C$ ranges over Borel subset. If you have a question please recall the context...

Comment: @YCor: Yes, of course, that is what I meant. (It's late here.)

Comment: @AlexM. I also mean I don't guess the context and only have a guess. you have the quotient of a topological group by the closure of $\{1\}$, it's clear that the pull-back of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the Hausdorff quotient equals the Borel  $\sigma$-algebra of the original group.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: The Kolmogorov quotient is always $T_0$, but not necessarily Hausdorff. Why do you claim that it will be so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Simon Rubinstein-Salzedo's ["On the existence and uniqueness of invariant measures on locally-compact groups"](http://simonrs.com/HaarMeasure.pdf) presents a proof of existence (and uniqueness up to a multiplicative strictly positive constant) of a left Haar measure given a locally-compact, not necessarily Hausdorff, group.

Comment: Do you know what definition of Radon measure he is using in that paper? A Borel measure that is locally finite and inner regular?

Comment: I don't know of any other definition. (Is there one?)

Comment: Of course there is another definition.  In fact, "Radon Measure" comes originally from Bourbaki, where it is defined as a certain type of linear functional.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to a recent paper that uses it that way?

Comment: I've seen various definitions of Radon measure. They seem to all be some combination of: locally finite, finite on compact subsets, inner regular, regular, quasi-regular (outer regular for all Borel sets but only inner regular for open sets), positive on nonempty open sets... If you do a google book search for Radon measure I think the chances are that no more than half of them will define Radon measure as "a Borel measure that is locally finite and inner regular". But I am ignorant and if someone with more knowledge would like to clarify usage of the term "Radon measure" I would be grateful.

Comment: @JasonDyer This comment is 7 years late: in Definition 5 of page 2 of that link one finds the notation $\mathcal{O}$ used to denote the collection of open sets, and on the 2nd to last line of page 3 it is thereby said that if $O$ is open and $K$ is a compact subset then $O \cap K^c$ is open. That is tantamount to knowing compact sets are closed.  How does one know such closedness if the group is not assumed to be Hausdorff?

Comment: @nfdc23 Isn't the property used in the paper actually equivalent (rather than just tantamount) to all compact sets being closed? It is asserted to work for all open sets $O$. So if we take $O$ to be the whole group, then the assertion is that $K$ compact implies $K^c$ open, right? If all compact sets are closed then the space is $T_1$. But topological groups are always completely regular. And comp. reg. + $T_1$ implies Hausdorff.

Comment: @Linden, are you sure that completely regular and $T_1$ implies Hausdorff? Algebraic groups (Abelian varieties, in particular) endowed with the Zariski topology are $T_1$ (a general property of the Zariski topology), are completely regular (being topological groups), but are not Hausdorff in general (again, a property of the Zariski topology).

Comment: @AlexM.: A $T_0$ topological group is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$, i.e. completely regular Hausdorff.

Comment: @tomasz: Indeed. And I also know where my comment was mistaken: an algebraic group is semi-topological, [but not necessarily topological](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Algebraic_group_not_implies_topological_group).

Comment: @AlexM.: Yes. In fact, it is topological if and only if it is finite (precisely for this reason).